# Странное поведение jQuery UI (droppable)

Tags: jquery-ui

Доброго времени суток.
Есть вот такой конструктор: http://dz.ipr-test.in.ua/

Суть вопроса в том, что при перетаскивании элементов на закладках "WEB" и "UI/UX" перетаскиваемые элементы дублируются. Т.е. повторно вызывается событие drop:

```
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
    jQuery( ui.draggable ).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', true ).addClass( 'move' );
    jQuery( ui.helper ).clone().appendTo( '#mokup-' + jQuery( ui.draggable ).parents( '.tab-pane.active' ).attr( 'id' ) + ' .mokup' );

    ...
```

Вот тут короткое видео проблемы: [AVI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3LxRar8WorWMDBsTmpfZHVBQXM/view?usp=sharing)

Не могу понять почему так происходит и как это побороть?

Answer (score 0):

В общем пока решение такое - через проверку наличия дропнутого элемента в принимающем блоке:

```
if ( ! jQuery( '.mokup > li[data-modid=' + jQuery( ui.helper ).data( 'modid' ) + ']' ).length ) {
    jQuery( ui.draggable ).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', true ).addClass( 'move' ); // inactiv donor-element
    jQuery( ui.helper ).clone().appendTo( '#mokup-' + jQuery( ui.draggable ).parents( '.tab-pane.active' ).attr( 'id' ) + ' .mokup' ); // clone donor-element and add drop-zone
}
```

IMXO: это решение ситуативное, так что хотелось бы все таки увидеть более универсальное решение проблемы :(